# react-native-maps marker clustering or performance improvement

Tags: react-native-maps

I use react-native-maps and custom markers. 
The number of markers are over than 1000.
Many article say react-native-maps clustering library such as react-native-maps-super-cluster help to optimize performance. 
However I found clustering function make delays in app performance.

So I hope to improve using another options (i.e. marker display according to view change?)

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
tracksViewChanges={false}
```

tracksViewChanges: Sets whether this marker should track view changes. It's recommended to turn it off whenever it's possible to improve custom marker performance.